# Subversion Merge - Possible to Ignore Merge History?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

**My basic problem is that I'm trying to re-merge trunk and a branch in Subversion 1.6, ignoring any previous merge history.**  My scenario is as follows:

1. I have a project in **trunk**.
2. I created a branch at **branches/branch-A**
3. Work continue on **trunk** and on **branch-A**
4. Since **branch-A** was a pretty big change, I have used TortoiseSVN to "**Merge a range of revisions**" from **trunk** to **branch-A** every week or so.  There were conflicts and I manually resolved them as they occurred.

At this point, **branch-A** should contain everything in trunk, plus the new feature.  This is mostly working but I'm seeing an issue that works in **trunk** and does not work in **branch-A**.  This makes me think that I incorrectly resolved a conflict in an earlier merge.

I'd like to do a merge that ignores my previous merge history and just does a straight **trunk** vs. **branch-A** diff.  When I try any merge now, it takes the merge history into account and does not show me any diffs for the conflicts I resolved earlier.  **Is this possible to ignore all previous merge history and just get an branch-A-vs.-trunk diff-merge?  Am I going about this incorrectly?**

Notes:

- I have tried to "merge a series of revisions" and "ignore ancestry" with no success.
- I do not care about keeping track of revisions in the branch.  When it is reintegrated, I'm planning to do it as one big merge revision for the new feature.
- I'm trying to "reintegrate" instead of "merge revisions" at the moment but it's going to take a while to run so I'm not sure if that's the magic bullet.

**UPDATE: The consensus seems to be that the "merge revisions" and "ignore ancestry" options should have given me what I asked for.  I ran the merge again and I got a nonsense tree conflict and nothing else, so I am going to assume that I fell into an edge case somewhere where the merge was not doing what it should have.  I knew approximately where the error should be so I ended up just diffing the entire trunk vs. the branch using DiffMerge, then finding and fixing the error manually.  Not clean but it worked.**

Comment: When you "Merged a range of revisions" in #4, were you leaving the box blank each time (e.g. to merge all unmerged revisions) ?

Comment: Yes, each time I merged from trunk, I left the box blank to merge all revisions.

Comment: Hmm, that's how I'd have done it so no issue there. On a separate note, don't try reintegrating trunk into the branch - reintegrate will be what you use when you are ready to merge your branch-A back into trunk. After a reintegrate, the branch should not be used further

Comment: For reference: [Subversion Merge Reintegrate](http://blogs.collab.net/subversion/2008/07/subversion-merg/)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I got too from reading the docs.  Oh well.  Thanks anyway.  I'm going to update the question and just assume that I had a weird edge case where it didn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the

```
--ignore-ancestry
```

flag which "causes the merging logic to mindlessly generate differences the same way that svn diff does, ignoring any historical relationships". From http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html

Comment: Please see the note I had at the bottom of my question.  I tried the --ignore-ancestry flag and did not see the results I expect.  If that definitely should give me what I want, I'll try again but so far, no luck. (Posted again because of a cut and paste error that I couldn't edit).